# Lipogram "quine"

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, quine

## Task

1. Take a single Unicode character as input.
2. Output a program in the same language that also obeys this specification, but which does not contain the input character.
3. If your program is run with input *a*, and then the output program is then run with input *b*, then the program *it* outputs is **ALLOWED** to contain character *a*. However, *b* is still not allowed to appear in this program. In other words, only the input into the most recent incarnation of the program is forbidden to appear.
4. Regardless of what the title may say, standard quine rules apply.

Shortest program wins. Program must be at least one byte long.

## Example

If the program is ABCD. (# is an comment)

```
> slangi "ABCD"
A
EBCD          # "FBCD" "JGGJ" "UGDKJGDJK" are all OK
> slangi "EBCD"
C
ABGD          # "EBGD" "UIHDAIUTD" are all OK
> slangi "ABGD"
B
AFCD
> slangi "AFCD"
Z
ABCD
```

Where `slangi` is an interpreter for a fictitious language.

Comment: Wouldn't this challenge less verbose languages? Several use words for instruction names, so it would be very difficult and/or impossible to avoid characters such as `e`.

Comment: It's very difficult to write in English without `e`, yet Gadsby does it.

Comment: I'm assuming no quine functions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## CJam, <s>45</s> <s>41</s> <s>38</s> 35 bytes

```
{`"OX$_?"+_l&{{H)+`}/"\He,}":)}&}_~
```

If the input character is none of the characters `` "$&)+,/:?HOX\_`el{} ``, this program prints the following, slightly modified version of itself. [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e2AiT1gkXz8iK19sJnt7SCkrYH0vIlxIZSx9IjopfSZ9X34&input=fg)

```
{`"OX$_?"+_l&{{H)+`}/"\He,}":)}&}OX$_?
```

Otherwise, the program prints the following, obfuscated version of the modification. [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e2AiT1gkXz8iK19sJnt7SCkrYH0vIlxIZSx9IjopfSZ9T1gkXz8&input=SA)

```
''r'4'a'j'6'q'Q'4'='q'~'8'''Z';'='r''A'4'n'Z'w'>''4'L';''8''a'j'6'q'Q]If-~
```

Note that some of the characters are unprintable. [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J8KNJ3InNCdhJ2onNidxJ1EnNCc9J3Enfic4J8KNJ8KNJ1onOyc9J3Inwo8nQSc0J24nWid3Jz4nwo8nNCdMJzsnwo8nOCfCjydhJ2onNidxJ1FdSWYtfg&input=SQ)

#### How it works

```
{`"OX$_?"+_l&{{H)+`}/"\He,}":)}&}_~

{                               }    Define a code block.
                                 _~  Push a copy and execute the copy.
 `                                   Push a string representation of the block.
  "OX$_?"                            Push that string.
         +_                          Concatenate and push a copy.
           l&                        Intersect the copy with the input.
             {                }&     If the intersection is non-empty:
              {    }/                  For each character of the concat. strings:
               H)                        Push 18.
                 +                       Add it to the character.
                  `                      Inspect; turn 'c into "'c".
                     "He,}"            Push that string.
                           :)          Increment each char. Pushes "If-~"
```

In the first possible output program, we avoid using `~` to be able to use it in the other program. Therefore, instead of `_~`, the modified program ends with `OX$_?`, which works as follows.

```
O        Push "" (falsy).
 X$      Push a copy of the code block.
   _     Push yet another copy.
    ?    Ternary if; since "" is falsy, execute the second copy.
```

Finally, in the remaining output program,

```
''r'4'a'j'6'q'Q'4'='q'~'8'''Z';'='r''A'4'n'Z'w'>''4'L';''8''a'j'6'q'Q]
```

wraps all those characters in an array, therefore pushing the following string.

```
"'4aj6qQ4=q~8'Z;=r'104nZw>'4L;'8'j6qQ"
```

`If-` subtracts 18 from each character code, pushing the string

```
"{`\"OX$_?\"+_l&{{H)+`}/\"\He,}\":)}&}OX$_?"
```

which `~` the evaluates.

Answer (score 18):

### JavaScript (ES6), <strike>356</strike> <strike>340</strike> <strike>327</strike> <strike>308</strike> <strike>303</strike> 263

Now using ```` Function`...``` ```` for the second program:

````js
f=(b=y=>[for(x of`f=${f};f()`)x.charCodeAt().toString(y).toUpperCase()])=>alert([`eval('\\${b(8).join('\\')}')`,`eval(String.fromCharCode(${b(10).map(x=>'+9-8'.repeat(x))}))`,'Function`\\x'+b(16).join('\\x')+'```'][1+"0e1v2a3l4(5'6'7)\\".indexOf(prompt())%2]);f()
````

---

The function packs itself into one of three possible programs:

1. The first program calls `eval` on a string literal containing the function's code with each character escaped as an octal value.

   ```
   eval('\146\165...')
   ```
2. The second program redirects the browser to a `javascript:` URL containing the function's code with each character URL encoded. This is the only way I could think to evaluate code without using parentheses. It also escapes the letters in 'eval'.

   ```
   window["\x6coc\x61tion"]["hr\x65f"]="j\x61\x76\x61script:%66%75..."
   ```
3. The last program is painfully long. It builds the function's code by adding one (`+9-8`) at a time to get each character code. This is to avoid using the octal digits.

   ```
   eval(String.fromCharCode(+9-8+9-8+9-8+9-8...))
   ```

The correct program is indexed by searching a carefully constructed string for the input character:

```js
[`program_1`,`program_3`,`program_2`][1+"0e1v2a3l4(5'6'7)\\".indexOf(prompt())%2]
```

Here's an ungolfed, untested version. It might not work because of newlines in the source.

```js
function f() {
    // convert source code of current function to bytes
    var bytes = Array.map(f + 'f()', x => x.charCodeAt());

    // pack this function's code in one of three possible programs,
    // depending on the input
    var input = prompt();

    // PROGRAM 1 - only contains characters: eval(')01234567\
    // eval('\146\165...')
    var source = "eval('\\" + bytes.map(x => x.toString(8)).join('\\') + "')";

    // PROGRAM 2 - doesn't contain characters: eval('')
    // window["\x6coc\x61tion"]["hr\x65f"]="j\x61\x76\x61script:%66%75..."
    // -> window["location"]["href"] = "javascript:..."
    if ("eval(')".includes(input)) {
        source = 'window["\\x6coc\\x61tion"]["hr\\x65f"]="j\\x61\\x76\\x61script:%';
        source += bytes.map(x => x.toString(16).toUpperCase()).join('%') + '"';
    }

    // PROGRAM 3 - doesn't contain characters: 01234567\
    // eval(String.fromCharCode(+9-8+9-8+9-8+9-8...))
    if ('01234567\\'.includes(input)) {
        source = "eval(String.fromCharCode(";
        source += bytes.map(x => '+9-8'.repeat(x)).join(',') + '))';
    }

    console.log(source);
}
f()
```

Comment: `function f(){ ... };f()` can be `(f=_=>{ ... })()`. Here's an example: http://www.es6fiddle.net/iiz2nq0l/

Comment: Even better: `f=(_=prompt())=>...;f()`. Input is stored as `_`.

Comment: Also, no need for console.log, function output is fine.

Comment: Won't using ```Function`[code]`.call``;``` work for you, instead of redirecting? Here is a working example: http://www.es6fiddle.net/ij023v49/ (See? No `evil()`! Erm, I mean `eval()`...)

Comment: Well, you have learned something today. Just be aware that the `this` object will be that empty template string. It relies on the `Function` constructor, which allows you to create a function, instead of running `eval()`. The function will have the code contained within the first parameter. I use it a lot to get the real `window`, using `Function('return this')()`. Since you can't use `()`, I've abused a little of ES6's kindness to try to spit an usable function that you can run without `()`. For that, you need the `.call()` method, which calls the function with a new  `this` object.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel can you use:

    Function`return 1```

Comment: @DomHastings You can use that, but it won't execute. The ```.call`` ``` is to make sure that it is called. Without it, you could do ```A=Function`return 1`,A```, with no byte savings.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel but it does call the function (as if with an empty param)? Apologies if I missed the need to use `call`, but if you aren't using `this` in the code that shouldn't matter right? I mostly wanted to share because I thought that three backticks in a row would be a syntax error and was surprised when they didn't! I did also wonder if using template string `eval` would be shorter too, but since you can't `return` anything from it probably not...

Comment: @DomHastings Now I see what you did there! That is magnificent! That is way cooler than my code! That is really quite a nice saving! The reason why I went this way is because on the 2nd function, you can't use any of the chars `eval(')`. grc found a way to execute code by redirecting to a `javascript:` url. Since the `Function` prototype doesnt contain any of the forbiden chars, I though he could use that to run his code. But you... You smashed it! Well done! Really good idea! I am surprised that it works as well!

Comment: Thanks. I've improved it, but It's a shame you can't use octal encoding inside string templates...